# Suma total de una columna y mostrar resultado a través de un textbox C# asp. Net

Tags: c#

Amigos su ayuda, 
como puedo obtener la suma total de una columna de un gridview y mostrar el resultado en un textbox?
Favor agradecería sus respuestas solo con lenguaje C# asp. Net

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta e indica lo que has hecho. Sin código, posiblemente tu pregunta sea cerrada.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si te ayudas con `linq` es bastante simple

```
var suma = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().
                        Sum(r=> Convert.ToDecimal(r.Cells["NombreColumna"].Value));

textbox1.Text = suma.ToString("N2");
```

Sino vas a tener que iterar cada row en un `foreach`, creo que con linq queda mas prolijo el codigo

Comment: Muchas gracias primeramente por tu respuesta. Pero como estoy trabajando mediante ASP.NET dentro del aspx.cs no me reconoce el DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()